# is it possible to write plain PHP code inside SLIM .php files

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I am beginner in PHP and almost no knowledge of SLIM framework. I have to add an insert query, as shown below, in a .php file of SLIM project.

```
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypw";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

$date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");

function get_client_ip()
{
  $ipaddress = '';
  if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
  else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
  else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
      $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
  else
      $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

  return $ipaddress;
}

$ipadr = get_client_ip();

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("mydb",$dbhandle) 
    or die("Unable select mydb");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `my_table` (`user-ip`,`user-date`) VALUES ('$ipadr','$date')");

mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

---

Can anyone help me how to do this? Is it possible to simply mix this plain php code with the SLIM framework code?
Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Simply put the code within a function and call that function from within your route callable.

Note that the `mysql` functions are very old and no longer available with PHP 7, so you should change them to use either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Not only is `mysql_` very old, it can leave you wide open to SQL injection attacks (as this code does)!  Many of those headers used to determine the value of `$ipadr` could easily be spoofed and populated with SQL injection code.